# Memoria compartida

Tags: c

Quiero que todos los procesos hijos escriban en una memoria compartida y el padre luego lo lea, tengo que introducir una serie de caracteres en ella, primer proceso escribe 2 caracterres, el segundo los 2 siguientes...
Luego leer este array por el padre, solo lee bien los del primer proceso.

```
padre.memCompartida = shmget(clavecompartida,sizeof(char*)*80 , IPC_CREAT | 0600);
clavecompartida = ftok("/tmp/acompartido",33);

if(padre.memCompartida==-1){
perror("Error al crear la memoria compartida\n");
exit(1);    
}

padre.punteroMem = (char *) shmat(padre.memCompartida, NULL, 0);
if(padre.punteroMem==(char *)-1){
perror("Error en el puntero a la zona de memoria compartida\n");
exit(1);    
}

//CREAR EL PROCESO PADRE Z de zacarias
    int i;


 for(i=0;i<NUM_HIJOS;i++)
    {
    switch(hijos[i].pid=fork())
     {
     case -1:
     printf("hubo un error en la creacion de los hijos.\n");
        return 3;
     case 0:
      //sleep(1);
  //INICIALIZACION DE LOS PROCESOS
  hijos[i].nombre=LETRAS[i];
  switch(hijos[i].nombre){
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
    hijos[i].grupo='1';
    break;

    case 'E':
    case 'e':
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
    hijos[i].grupo='2';
    break;

    case 'I':
    case 'i':
    case 'J':
    case 'j':
    case 'L':
    case 'l':
    case 'M':
    case 'm':
    hijos[i].grupo='3';
    break;

    case 'N':
    case 'n':
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
    hijos[i].grupo='4';
    break;
  }

  hijos[i].memCompartida=padre.memCompartida
  **hijos[i].punteroMem=padre.punteroMem;**

 ** padre.punteroMem[2*i]=hijos[i].nombre;**
 ** padre.punteroMem[i+1]=hijos[i].grupo;**



      exit (0);
     }
     }



    for(i=0;i<63;i++){
      printf("%c",padre.punteroMemoria[i];

    printf ("Precione ENTER para liberar los recursos compartidos\n");
    getchar ();
    shmctl (padre.memCompartida, IPC_RMID,(struct shmid_ds *)NULL);
  } //FIN MAIN
```

Comment: Por favor, considera editar la pregunta porque tal y como está escrita no hay por donde cogerla. ¿Que es `padre`? ¿y `hijos`? ¿Qué es esa parte del código que está con asteriscos? ¿En qué punto te falla el código? Intenta publicar un ejemplo completo con el código mínimo que permita reproducir el problema y explica a partir de ese código cual es tu problema.

Comment: Faltan los valores iniciales de algunas variables, la definición de `main`, los `includes` que usas, etc. ¿Podrías proporcionarnos un [ejemplo mínimo funcional (MCVE)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Gracias.

Comment: En casi 24 horas el OP no ha editado su pregunta, propongo cerrarla a la espera de que aclare los cabos sueltos de la pregunta